# Why this join provide multiple value?

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-8.0, distinct

**This is my Query:**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.categoryName) AS categories
FROM post p
         INNER JOIN join_post_cat jpc USING (postId)
         INNER JOIN categories c USING (categoryId)
WHERE p.postId = 1;
```

**This is Output:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| categories                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Apartment/Flat,Auditorium,Bachelor,Community Center |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**This is another Query:**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.areaName) AS locations
FROM join_area ja
         INNER JOIN area a ON ja.belongAreaId = a.areaId
WHERE ja.areaId = 29;
```

**This is Output:**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| locations                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Dhaka Division,Dhaka Zhila,Dhaka City,Jatrabari,West Jatrabari |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> Those two queries data are related with each others by `ONE TO MANY` relationship. So when i marge both two queries in one Query, those Output got repeated.

**This is updated Query:**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.categoryName) AS categories,
       GROUP_CONCAT(a.areaName)     AS locations
FROM post p
         INNER JOIN join_post_cat jpc USING (postId)
         INNER JOIN categories c USING (categoryId)
         INNER JOIN join_area ja USING (areaId)
         INNER JOIN area a ON ja.belongAreaId = a.areaId
WHERE p.postId = 1;
```

**This is Output:**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| categories                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | locations                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Apartment/Flat,Apartment/Flat,Apartment/Flat,Apartment/Flat,Apartment/Flat,Auditorium,Auditorium,Auditorium,Auditorium,Auditorium,Bachelor,Bachelor,Bachelor,Bachelor,Bachelor,Community Center,Community Center,Community Center,Community Center,Community Center | Dhaka Division,Dhaka Zhila,Dhaka City,Jatrabari,West Jatrabari,Dhaka Division,Dhaka Zhila,Dhaka City,Jatrabari,West Jatrabari,Dhaka Division,Dhaka Zhila,Dhaka City,Jatrabari,West Jatrabari,Dhaka Division,Dhaka Zhila,Dhaka City,Jatrabari,West Jatrabari |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

> When i add `distinct` inside `GROUP_CONCAT` i got the desired output.

**This is the Query with Correct Output:**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.categoryName) AS categories,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct a.areaName)     AS locations
FROM post p
         INNER JOIN join_post_cat jpc USING (postId)
         INNER JOIN categories c USING (categoryId)
         INNER JOIN join_area ja USING (areaId)
         INNER JOIN area a ON ja.belongAreaId = a.areaId
WHERE p.postId = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| categories                                          | locations                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Apartment/Flat,Auditorium,Bachelor,Community Center | Dhaka Division,Dhaka Zhila,Dhaka City,Jatrabari,West Jatrabari |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### **Now i want to know:**

- **Why MySQL get same data multiple times?**
- **Why do i need to add `distinct`? (I know to remove duplicate data but    why MySQL get those data multiple time)**
- **Is there any better way to do this task without getting duplicate    data or without using `distinct` or `group`?**

**Those Tables Diagram:**

[image]

Comment: @mustaccio There are three main tables `post`, `categories` and `area`. `join_post_cat` has `many to one` relationship with `post` and `categories` tables. `join_area` has `many to one` relationship with `area` tables, also `post` table as relation with `area` table by holding areaId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way...

Step 1.  Build all combinations of rows requested by the `JOINs`.
Step 2.  Do the `GROUP BY`.

What to do instead?

Yeah, you could do a `DISTINCT`.  But that only hides the problem that the query is doing too much work.

Instead, separate the `GROUP BYs`:

```
SELECT ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.categoryName)
              FROM categories WHERE c.categoryId = p.categoryId
       ) AS categories,
       ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.areaName)
              FROM join_area WHERE ja.areaId = p.areaId  -- (or whatever)
       )      AS locations
FROM post p
WHERE p.postId = 1;
```

OK, having subqueries costs something, but at least you are getting the de-dupped answer without taking extra effort to de-dup.

Be sure to follow the tips on many:many tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: i know the highest number of duplicate data i will get, its will not be more than 5. So in that case subqueries will perform better or distinct will be enough? i means when will join second query (area table) i know there can be maximum 5row.

Comment: @Rhidoy - For under a million rows in the table, the difference is probably small.  Try them both.  Time them.

Comment: @Rhidoy - and I added a reference for many:many tips.